# How can i pass EmployeeID as in NameID in saml assertion

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

As by default OneLogin passes Email as NameID in SAML assertion.
But i want to pass EmployeeID as NameID in SAML assertion. So that i would be able to identify user on the basis of EmployeeID.

Is there any way to do so or OneLogin provides?

Answer (score 1):

In the application configuration go to parameters and edit the value for SAMLNameId[image]